# One-hot encoding decimals to labels?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to encode a range of frequencies i.e. 15.7 Hz into a label so that I can train a CNN model. When encoding 0 - 50 Hz with a 1Hz step I can simply use `to_categorical` but once I reduce the step size to a decimal I cant use this anymore. Is there an alternative?

```
Y_train = to_categorical(y_train,num_classes=50)
```

**Output:**

```
(6800,50) i.e. 6800 signals with 50 frequency classes.
```

Comment: My answer is simple - JUST DON'T. You should use `to_categorical` to encode your `y_train` and instead you can make a dictionary to decode you outputs. To your model it doesn't matter what is the actual label. It will train only on the discrete numeric value and hence it won't impact your model training.

Comment: But I have repeating values within that Y_train set i.e. I may have x80 (28.4 Hz frequencies) so I dont want to create duplicate labels for the same thing? @AbishekPrajapat

Comment: When I use to_categorical it is converting the class vector (integers) to binary class vectors. I think its rounding up on me when I give it a value of say 28.9 its rounding up to 29 and giving it a binary class which isnt what I want. Therefore I don't think it is possible to use to_categorical. @AbishekPrajapat

Comment: Then just use a label encoder on y_train before  feeding in to the dataset.